# filemaker 9 prints only 1 record per label sheet

Tags: printing, filemaker

I have some records that I am trying to print to label sheets in Filemaker 9
I am only getting [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnePa.png) record printed.

When I view in Preview mode I see a full page of properly formated records in three columns.

Yes - I am selecting "Records being browsed" in print dialog

Here is a shot of the layout. This should print properly.

[layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnePa.png)

Comment: Yes, Records being browsed is the major offender. The other one is having only one record in found set at the time you print. Try to post the extract from your script

Answer (score 0):

Records being browsed will usually only return the last viewed related record.

So ensure you've got somewhere you can search for your required fields, so if it was address labels.
Create a Table view as well - then have you Address 1, Postcode, Country etc.

And that way when you go to Label Print view it will have a record count associated with it